# Can Fortify scan results be saved into a file?

Tags: fortify, fortify-source

Can I save fortify scan results into a file, so I can send to someone to Analyze them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a report using Audit Work Bench or Software Security Center. PDF reports typically don't contain enough detail to see all of the information regarding a vulnerability, but if the other person doesn't have Fortify it's better than nothing.

You can also try posting Fortify issues to their online forum at https://protect724.hp.com. The support group monitors those forums.

Comment: No problem, happy scanning =)